# Click is not working in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an image with the Coupon code in Front End/Homepage of my website but when I try to click that nothing happens and click is not working.

The **Html** is below

```
<a class="coupon_click text-no-decoration" href="javascript:void(0);" id="coupon_id_<?php echo $couponBanner->getId(); ?>">
```

**jQuery** code is below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.coupon_click').click(function () {
        console.log('here');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo url_for('@blog_couponClicked') ?>',
            data: {videoId: <?php echo $video_id ?>, couponId: <?php echo $couponBanner->getId(); ?>},
            success: function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    window.location.href = res;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you able to `console.log` 'here' successfully?

Comment: Any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: did you append that `<a>` tag? if yes try **`jQuery(document).on('click','.coupon_click',function () {`**

Comment: @Eddie no nothing is shown in there

Comment: is `coupon_click` link being added using `javascript/jquery`? @LaravelWarrior

Comment: @ShadowFiend not working

Comment: @Eddie it is printed in the page via PHP Symfony

Comment: Any errors on the dev tool? @LaravelWarrior

Comment: The script I was calling was in if statement and that if statement was not executing, so I removed it from the if block and it worked! Thank you so much all!

Answer (score 0):

Hi my advise don't mess the JQuery Code and PHP and make it clean as much as possible,

```
         <a class="coupon_click text-no-decoration" href="javascript:void(0);" c-id="coupon_id_<?php echo $couponBanner->getId(); ?>" v-id="<?php echo $video_id ?>">Click</>




jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                  jQuery('.coupon_click').on('click', function () {
                    console.log('here');
                   var cid= jQuery(this).attr('c-id');
                   var vid= jQuery(this).attr('v-id');
                   dataCall(vid,cid);
              })

       function dataCall(vId, cId){
              jQuery.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'your_url',
                      data: {videoId: vId,couponId:cId},
                      success: function (res) {
                      //do whatever you want to do
                  },error:function(err){
                     console.log(err);
               }
            })

      }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it's what u want

```
<a id="coupon" class="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="coupon_id">coupon</a>


$("document").ready(function()
{
    $("#coupon").click(function ()
    {
        sendS();
    });

});


function sendS()
{
    var couponID="abc123";//anythg u like
    var userID="hahaha@mail.com";
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"php.php",
        data:{cID:couponID,uID:userID},

        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function () 
        {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    }); 
}
```